# Jquery-Tools Tabs AJAX Caching... so close yet so far

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, tabs, jquery-tools

JqueryTools Tabs is really wonderful [http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax.html]. The only catch is that these AJAX-enabled tabs don't do any caching. So each tab click means a fresh reload each time.

We're almost there though, take a look at these threads : [http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/25/74554] and [http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/25/32829]. Unfortunately I haven't gotten it to work with my implementation which is essentially this one [http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax.html].

Has anybody solved this one? Please share it, many JqueryTools Tabs users all around the world will be eternally grateful !! (At least one will be).

Thank you,

Gene

Comment: You'd be best off finding some other jQuery plugin.  jQuery Tools was last updated over a year ago, requires too much markup, is poorly supported, is not fully compatible with IE 9, and it seems the developer has lost all interest.

Comment: @Sparkt672 - I have to disagree, I find jQuery Tools to very useful and although is has been stagnent as of late, the developer has not lost interest http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/20/66697

Comment: @MattoTodd, it's all a matter of opinion and how one defines "lost interest".  It has not been updated since jQuery 1.4.2 so use at your own risk.  All his dithering over the last year certainly damaged its reputation, perhaps beyond repair. I, for one, am never going back.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't wanna reload each tab for each click, why don't you render the whole page at once. One of the reasons you can load the tabs via ajax is so that you can get updates without having to reload the whole page. If you want the tabs to be cached, load the whole page at once, and you'll save yourself the overhead of a request for each tab the first time it loads.

Ajax is great for some things, but unnecessary for others.